# Problema con la validación de selección de radio button en JavaScript: alerta no funciona correctamente y permite continuar sin seleccionar una opción

Tags: javascript

Este código en teoría funcionaba, consiste en seleccionar un personaje entre 3 opciones posibles, y si no selecciono ninguno me tiraba un alert y no me deja avanzar hasta seleccionar uno, pero por algún motivo dejó de funcionar y cuando no selecciono ningún personaje me tira el alert de igual manera, pero me deja seguir sin seleccionar un personaje

```
let inputRatigueya = document.getElementById('ratigueya')
let inputHipodoge = document.getElementById('hipodoge')
let inputCapipepo = document.getElementById('capipepo')
let mascot = document.getElementById('select-mascot')

if (inputRatigueya.checked){
    mascot.innerHTML = 'Ratigueya'
} 
else if (inputHipodoge.checked){
    mascot.innerHTML ='Hipodoge'
}  
else if (inputCapipepo.checked){
    mascot.innerHTML ='Capipepo'
}   
else {
    alert("Select a character")
}
```

Comment: No hay nada en ese código que restrinja nada. Ni antes ni ahora. Sólo valida el estado de unos elementos HTML y modifica otros o muestra un alert. Eso no va a "detener" la ejecución de otra cosa. El problema debe estar en cómo estás usando esto para "seguir", lo que sea que haga tu código después. Creo que te toca ampliar la pregunta yendo a [edit] y mostrando cómo usas ésto

Comment: A esta pregunta le faltan más detalles y aclaraciones, véase cómo [preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), saludos.

Comment: Tu código está incompleto; no tiene donde reportas/retornas si es o no válido para continuar/detener el proceso.